# c# Xml Deserializar XML con 2 elementos con el mismo nombre

Tags: c#, xml

Hola tengo un Xml el cual no puedo modificar (se genera con un programa de terceros) pero tiene 2 elementos con el mismo nombre y no me deja deserealizar.

El elemento es Impuestos

Este es el xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Serie="ARR" Folio="7" Fecha="2019-01-15T09:47:37" FormaPago="04" NoCertificado="30001000000300023708" Certificado="MIIF+TCr" SubTotal="22000.00" Moneda="USD" TipoCambio="20.000000" Total="20972.60" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="10400"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Sello="YXtPffJNQo22+f+QabNvZfoVteeP8vcQssYldySNd2oXXOitQSAWuheysCURyaDuLNE4FPwyJO/KWhtZJDHnhdP2BbEPHygv5tqe1szfH6HKUAtxv+ar2n23xjSCJcuu84QqZsfBXhQlSB5Ckm8w7/s3Eup0dpEg8FkBefItMRFr5Tlp5V4aZXBevyMlf5NBrYT8dhIV4uCvAz6vC0tp1Qxr5ATH1J3YdESoksEL/7FD6QFPX0jJWK5zsCZ5N0cEG2nh3+VxQ/VgL46YrGjLffD/ZqdrUtb+ZRqOjWkcp6MGHb1P0e/CHfTnd+7KxT3wfnik/Kdc7+URcOzBwEvaRg==">
<cfdi:Emisor Rfc="AAA010101AAA" Nombre="VANGUARDIA, S.A. DE C.V." RegimenFiscal="601"></cfdi:Emisor>
<cfdi:Receptor Rfc="ZZA021106K74" Nombre="Gasolinera Universal S.A. DE C.V" UsoCFDI="G03"></cfdi:Receptor>
<cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="80131502" NoIdentificacion="21" Cantidad="8" ClaveUnidad="MON" Unidad="MES" Descripcion="Renta de locales" ValorUnitario="2750.00" Importe="22000.00">
        <cfdi:Impuestos>
            <cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Traslado Base="22000.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="3520.00"></cfdi:Traslado>
            </cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Retenciones>
                <cfdi:Retencion Base="22000.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.106700" Importe="2347.40"></cfdi:Retencion>
                <cfdi:Retencion Base="22000.00" Impuesto="001" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.100000" Importe="2200.00"></cfdi:Retencion>
            </cfdi:Retenciones>
        </cfdi:Impuestos>
        <cfdi:CuentaPredial Numero="15956011002"></cfdi:CuentaPredial>
    </cfdi:Concepto>
</cfdi:Conceptos>
<cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosRetenidos="4547.40" TotalImpuestosTrasladados="3520.00">
    <cfdi:Retenciones>
        <cfdi:Retencion Impuesto="001" Importe="2200.00"></cfdi:Retencion>
        <cfdi:Retencion Impuesto="002" Importe="2347.40"></cfdi:Retencion>
    </cfdi:Retenciones>
    <cfdi:Traslados>
        <cfdi:Traslado Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="3520.00"></cfdi:Traslado>
    </cfdi:Traslados>
</cfdi:Impuestos>
<cfdi:Complemento>
    <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital RfcProvCertif="TSP080724QW6" Version="1.1" UUID="ED318636-89E7-4A6B-B4F2-F8E710855264" FechaTimbrado="2019-01-15T09:47:37" SelloCFD="YX==" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/timbrefiscaldigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd"
        xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
    </cfdi:Complemento>
</cfdi:Comprobante>
```

y cuando trato de deserializar sale el error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si exista alguna forma de deserializar ese xml ya que no lo puedo cambiar :(

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo, no se si sea la mejor manera pero lo que hice fue cambiar el nombre del elemento con XElement

```
string Xml = File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/Luis/Downloads/xmlejemplo.xml");

        XElement XDoc = XElement.Parse(Xml);
        XNamespace space = Comprobante.CFDI_NAMESPACE;
        var Element = XDoc.Element(space + "Impuestos");
        Element.Name = space + "ImpuestoComprobante";

        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Comprobante));

        using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(XDoc.ToString())) {
            Comprobante result = (Comprobante)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
```